# Nativescript okhttp undefined

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

The native-script http unfortunately does not support gzip on android, hence I am exploring the usage of okhttp addin in angular app. So far I have installed the addin and imported it on top of the ng service:

```
let okHttp = require("nativescript-okhttp");
```

No errors are observed during compilation. However when I do call

```
var result = okHttp.getString("http://www.google.com/");
```

I am getting the *TypeError: Cannot read property 'okhttp' of undefined*

Also, based on the addin readme it is not clear how to perform basic POST api call with custom headers. It would be great if somebody can shed some light on how to use the okhttp addin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out nativescript-https?
https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https

It imports the okhttp3 library for android. Also the readme specifies how to create a POST request with custom headers:

```
import * as Https from 'nativescript-https'
Https.request({
    url: 'https://wegossipapp.com/api/newuser',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ZWx1c3VhcmlvOnlsYWNsYXZl',
        'x-uuid': 'aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY',
        'x-version': '4.2.0',
        'x-env': 'DEVELOPMENT',
    },
    content: JSON.stringify({
        'username': 'roblav96',
        'password': 'password',
    })
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('Https.request response', response)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Https.request error', error)
})
```

If you are getting lots of errors on deploy, it is due to the TypeScript compiler, and this issue addresses that:
https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https/issues/16

Also there seems to be a new issue with setting url:
https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https/issues/22

No solution given to that one yet. However I think it just means the url is now outside of the HttpsRequestOptions, so possibly just write it like:

```
Https.request('https://wegossipapp.com/api/newuser',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ZWx1c3VhcmlvOnlsYWNsYXZl',
        'x-uuid': 'aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY',
        'x-version': '4.2.0',
        'x-env': 'DEVELOPMENT',
    },
    content: JSON.stringify({
        'username': 'roblav96',
        'password': 'password',
    })
})
```

Comment: yes i have but it simply doesnt work. i have created hello world project and added nativscript-https plugin. the first issue i see is that i cannot define the url, after pulling the sample from github and during the deploy i do have bunch of errors, specifically nsobject and java is not defined etc. is there any workable sample where i can just perfom a basic api call

Comment: havent looked into it too much, but added in some links to the answer which mention your issues.